# 2D layering/URP issue when using fence tiles

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development, topdown, urp

[image: Character runs into fence and appears correctly above fence]

[image: Character runs into fence and incorrectly appears above fence][image: URP to show that axis is (0, 1, 0)]

I am working on my first real 2D unity game. I only recently started using URP to display my character behind barrels and cacti correctly. I am now using a fence tile set I created with collider boxes along the bottom edges of the fence. However, when the player's y-value is greater than that of the fence, the player incorrectly appears above the fence (It does appear correctly when the player's y-value is less than the fence's.

I think it has something to do with pivots, however when I try to adjust pivots, sprites do not perform as intended. Also, they are located on the same layer.

Thank you in advance for any help. Please ask if you need any clarification.

EDIT: Most of the fence tiles are two tiles in height. I switched the collider type to None for the tops of fences so that they wouldn't collide with the player. Could this be a problem?

[image: Camera Component]

Comment: Have you tried changing the `Transparency Sort Axis` under Edit -> Project Settings -> Graphics -> Transparency Sort Axis to (0, 1, 0) ?

Comment: Yes, I have changed the Transparency Sort Axis to (0, 1, 0) under my 2D renderer. I will edit the post to add a screenshot.

Comment: Is the player sprite always shown on top or is there just a region where is wrong?

Comment: The player always appears above the fence.

Comment: Can you confirm that both sprites are on the same `sorting layer` and `order in layer`? If you've installed URP after the fact, check that the pipeline is active Edit -> Project Settings -> Graphics -> Scriptable Render Pipeline Settings. Also check if your camera has "Universal Additional Camera Data" script and that it has adjusted the camera component (if its all good you should see drop down menus on the camera component)

Comment: I can confirm all. However, I will add a screenshot of my camera settings, as I'm not entirely sure about the camera component.

Comment: I'd need to see the camera component parameters. I could offer you to look over the project, if you are comfortable to upload it on github or make a unitypackage of the scene and upload it to some file sharing site.

Comment: I have uploaded the project to GitHub. Still relatively new to me, so let me know if there is anything I can do to make it easier. Here is a link: https://github.com/ColeWhaley1/WildWest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change a number of configurations to resolve your issue.

1. Remove the `Sort Group` Component from the "Fences" gameobject. It is intended for something different and messes with sorting.
2. Change the Mode of the Tilemap Render on the "Fences" gameobject, so that it is set to `Individual`. This is the intended mode for interweaving transparent tilemaps and other sprites. See [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.2/Documentation/Manual/Tilemap-Isometric-RenderModes.html) for more information.
3. Merge your lower fence and upper fence tiles into a single rectangular tile in the Sprite Editor. Adjust the pivot point so that it sits at the center of your lower tile and redo the custom collision shape. This step is necessary so that your character doesn't pop half way thru the fence. It will also save you some sanity when designing the map.

[image: rectangular fence tile with adjusted custom pivot]